# Error running Gradle flutter android studio

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I'm trying to run my flutter project, but it shows some error

> Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 6 in debug mode...
>   Initializing gradle...
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   * Error running Gradle:
>   ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\finalCode\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>
> Configure project :onesignal
>   WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Configure project :audioplayer
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> Configure project :contact_picker
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> Configure project :assets_audio_player
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
>
> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
>   WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
>            *********************************************************
>   WARNING: This version of image_picker will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
>            See ..... for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
>            This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
>            *********************************************************
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
>     The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
>     project ':assets_audio_player' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 6s
>     Command: C:\Users\admin\Downloads\finalCode\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
>
> Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.2, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    // splits {
    //     abi {
    //         enable true
    //         reset()
    //         include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
    //         universalApk false
    //     }
    // }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mustafakhaled.buzzchat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: Thanks, I added code too

Answer (score 0):

My error was that i forgot to accept the licences of flutter:

```
flutter doctor
```

If this show an X about the licenses:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Hope this work, happy coding.